# Breaking down Log Analytics query results with Logic Apps

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics

Evening all,

we are trying to use a logic app to translate the output of Azure Monitor alerts into something that our call logging system can use.

The webhook (cannot use the logic app output in the alert action group as the logic app is in a different subscription and tenant) sends the HTML code across to the logicapp and we can extract all the information.

However we have an issue where the query results themselves are coming across as a table and we can't figure out how to split multiple results into a foreach loop or extract it out to an array etc.

The format we are trying to break out is as below and I can't figure out how to manipulate the columns and rows areas into something useful.

```
[
  {
    "name": "PrimaryResult",
    "columns": [
      {
        "name": "OSFamily",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "TimeGenerated",
        "type": "datetime"
      },
      {
        "name": "Computer",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "InstanceName",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "CounterValue",
        "type": "real"
      },
      {
        "name": "Threshold",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "DisplayName",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "AzureSubscriptionId",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "CustomerName",
        "type": "string"
      }
    ],
    "rows": [
      [
        "windows",
        "2021-01-14T14:25:23.48Z",
        "server1",
        "F:",
        62.8117027282715,
        "< 70%",
        "abc",
        "4343113b-f400-4792-9c9d-fc2202f6314a",
        "Customer1"
      ],
      [
        "windows",
        "2021-01-14T14:25:12.283Z",
        "server2",
        "C:",
        48.0810470581055,
        "< 70%",
        "abc",
        "4343113b-f400-4792-9c9d-fc2202f6314a",
        "Customer1"
      ],
      [
        "windows",
        "2021-01-14T14:25:12.283Z",
        "server3",
        "F:",
        12.9271459579468,
        "< 70%",
        "abc",
        "4343113b-f400-4792-9c9d-fc2202f6314a",
        "Customer1"
      ],
      [
        "windows",
        "2021-01-14T14:25:12.283Z",
        "server4",
        "H:",
        51.2177963256836,
        "< 70%",
        "abc",
        "4343113b-f400-4792-9c9d-fc2202f6314a",
        "Customer1"
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

We have tried multiple variations of ParseJSON with no success, we can't seem to separate out "Columns" or "Rows", and also a few things with expressions around createarray but I'm simply not up to speed enough on this side of things to know what I want to do.

The end game is to generate an email for each row in that table.

Thanks
Andy